# How to connect to MySQL database with HipHop PHP?

Tags: mysql, centos, centos5

I installed hiphop php in CentOS 5.4 via yum with the repositories provided in the guide of the Git repository. Yum installed all the needed packages, including "mysql51".

The problem is, i can't turn on the database using:

**"service mysqld start"** or **"/etc/init.d/mysqld start"**

Even when I list all the services available "service --status-all" mysql doesn't appear. So, how I will turn on the database and then connect to store my data?

Comment: What does this have to do with HipHop? You've broken your MySQL database. Check the MySQL error logs in /var/log.

Comment: FYI, yum only installed the client instead of the server because that would count as "minimum requirement"

Comment: @Tim Good call. Someone running HipHop in production should have a separate server hosting the DB, so it makes sense that it'd leave that out.

Comment: Actually is a development server, so it should be ok to have a MySQL server installed there.

Comment: Yes, but you have to install that MySQL server. HipHop won't, because it (reasonably) assumes said server will be somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that on CentOS 'mysql51" package is the client, "mysql51-server" is the server package. This is the one you want:

```
yum install mysql51-server
```

Comment: I have a conflict when try to install mysql:
Processing Conflict: mysql51 conflicts mysql < 5.1

Comment: if you use the mysql51 client application, you should install mysql51-server package. I've edited my answer to make it clearer.